# Displaying info in DIV based on dropdown option chosen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been attempting a few different approaches for this. I began with an accordion but the page was going to be too tall, even with subgroups. A modal was considered but that meant having something pop up on the user's screen. Tabs were considered for this too so the user could select a year and month to show past events but this quickly becomes messy. `<details>` was considered but isn't flexible enough.

I've settled thinking a drop-down is the best way to go about this and then show the correct data in the DIV below it. I'm just not sure on an approach but I think the foundation is fine. The idea is that the option value `option value="value"` being selected would then trigger a DIV with a matching class to become visible, so `<div class="value">`. The previous value would need to be hidden when a new one is chosen.

Each DIV will have dynamic content from another source within it but each month a new section will be manually added, if this were to be done with scripting it would need to work based on displaying a match to the value so the script doesn't need to be constantly changed with every new addition.

The DIV will either be not present, show a message saying "You need to make a selection above first" or show the information from the latest month available.

Below is what I have so far, unsure how to implement this display swapping.

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content">

  <div class="noselection">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div class="January20">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div class="February20">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div class="March20">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div class="April20">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div class="May20">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div class="June20">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div class="July20">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div class="August20">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div class="September20">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div class="October20">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div class="November20">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div class="December20">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div class="January21">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div class="February21">Content from February 2021</div>


</div>
```

Any information about styling a custom drop-down would also be useful if this would work better, I'm just not sure how to get the desired effect but the design is there. A solution without reliance on an external library and JS not jQuery would be best, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#menu').on( 'change keyup', function() {
        var selected = this.value;
        // Load data
        $('.noselection').hide();
        $('.hideprev').hide();      
        $('.' + selected).show();
});
});
</script>
<select id="menu">
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content">

  <div class="noselection">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="January20 hideprev">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="February20 hideprev">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="March20 hideprev">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="April20 hideprev">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="May20 hideprev">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="June20 hideprev">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="July20 hideprev">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="August20 hideprev">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="September20 hideprev">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="October20 hideprev">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="November20 hideprev">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="December20 hideprev">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="January21 hideprev">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="February21 hideprev">Content from February 2021</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is close but it adds the content each time. When another option is selected the first one should be set to invisible

Comment: @helpmeplease no problem

Comment: Few issues with Ajax, I'm guessing pure JS solutuion isn't possible w/o jquery?? External libraries can't be used on the page, just JS scripts.

Comment: Just download jquery locally then and run that way

Comment: Jquery is written in js anyway see the extension  .JS

Comment: @helpmeplease just download it locally if cross site scripts are blocked. The link is https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js